# How to remove data from the phone number and the last comma. using sed or awk

Tags: awk, sed

So basically I have a text file with hundreds of lines like this..

```
2020-04-13 17:09:58.934,/abc/blahblahblahI/v1/dennisritchie/7408058445,2020-04-13 17:09:58.687,2020-04-13 17:09:58.934
2020-04-13 17:09:59.387,/cde/bunnyrabbit/v1/tea/generate/9161455644,2020-04-13 17:09:59.322,2020-04-13 17:09:59.387
2020-04-13 17:09:59.567,/fgh/scoobybites/v1/shaggy/markup/7672748033,2020-04-13 17:09:59.459,2020-04-13 17:09:59.567
2020-04-13 17:09:59.640,/xxx/xxxxxxxxxxxxxx/v1/xxx/generate,2020-04-13 17:09:59.624,2020-04-13 17:09:59.640
2020-04-13 17:09:59.796,/yyyy/defoe/v1/aaaaaaaaaal/9820276621?noOfRecords=1&blahlahAccountNo,2020-04-13 17:09:59.523,2020-04-13 17:09:59.796
2020-04-13 17:09:59.780,/dcd/manual/v2/profile/9841001122?fields=billingArrangement,billingAccountNo,faId,2020-04-16 09:59:59.740,2020-04-16 09:59:59.825
```

The main aim is to look like this, to remove everything with the phonenumbers till the last comma ( only in the lines with phone numbers ), and it should look like this.

```
2020-04-13 17:09:58.934,/abc/blahblahblahI/v1/dennisritchie/,2020-04-13 17:09:58.687,2020-04-13 17:09:58.934
2020-04-13 17:09:59.387,/cde/bunnyrabbit/v1/tea/generate/,2020-04-13 17:09:59.322,2020-04-13 17:09:59.387
2020-04-13 17:09:59.567,/fgh/scoobybites/v1/shaggy/markup/,2020-04-13 17:09:59.459,2020-04-13 17:09:59.567
2020-04-13 17:09:59.640,/xxx/xxxxxxxxxxxxxx/v1/xxx/generate,2020-04-13 17:09:59.624,2020-04-13 17:09:59.640
2020-04-13 17:09:59.796,/yyyy/defoe/v1/aaaaaaaaaal/,2020-04-13 17:09:59.523,2020-04-13 17:09:59.796
2020-04-13 17:09:59.780,/dcd/manual/v2/profile/, ,2020-04-16 09:59:59.740,2020-04-16 09:59:59.825
```

Got a few solutions in stockoverflow, The solution works fine on all the lines except the lines looking like the last one.

If you notice the last line is a bit different it should look like the following,

```
2020-04-13 17:09:59.780,/dcd/manual/v2/profile,2020-04-16 09:59:59.740,2020-04-16 09:59:59.825
```

But instead it looks like this, please help

```
2020-04-13 17:09:59.780,/dcd/manual/v2/profile,billingAccountNo,faId,2020-04-16 09:59:59.740,2020-04-16 09:59:59.825
```

Other Solutions I got in stackoverflow..

```
sed -E 's|/[0-9]+[^,]*,|/,|' or sed -E 's|/[0-9]{10}[^,]*,|/,|'
```

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} {sub(/[0-9]{10}.*/,"",$2)} 1'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you please try following, this will remove everything from phone number to last comma in 2nd field.

```
awk '{sub(/[0-9]{10}.*,/,",",$2)} 1'  Input_file
```

Answer (score 1):

If you simply want to remove the 10-digits in-a-row phone number, then you can use `[0-9]` with a *repetition* of `10`, e.g. (with BRE)

```
sed 's/[0-9]\{10\}//' file
```

or with ERE

```
sed -E 's/[0-9]{10}//' file
```

With a slight change to substitute you could remove from the 10-digit phone number to end:

```
sed 's/[0-9]\{10\}.*$//' file
```

**Remove Phone to Next to Last `','`**

Finally, to preserve the contents between the last two `','` after the phone as indicated in the comment, instead simply anchoring to the end with `'$'`, you would just create a *capture group* of `[^,]*,.*$` to preserve the text and then re-insert the captured text with the first numbeered *backreference* (`\1`) producing the output you show in the comment below.

```
sed 's/[0-9]\{10\}.*\(,[^,]*,.*$\)/\1/' file
```

(or with ERE)

```
sed -E 's/[0-9]{10}.*(,[^,]*,.*$)/\1/' file
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ sed 's/[0-9]\{10\}.*\(,[^,]*,.*$\)/\1/' file
2020-04-13 17:09:58.934,/abc/blahblahblahI/v1/dennisritchie/,2020-04-13 17:09:58.687,2020-04-13 17:09:58.934

2020-04-13 17:09:59.387,/cde/bunnyrabbit/v1/tea/generate/,2020-04-13 17:09:59.322,2020-04-13 17:09:59.387

2020-04-13 17:09:59.567,/fgh/scoobybites/v1/shaggy/markup/,2020-04-13 17:09:59.459,2020-04-13 17:09:59.567

2020-04-13 17:09:59.640,/xxx/xxxxxxxxxxxxxx/v1/xxx/generate,2020-04-13 17:09:59.624,2020-04-13 17:09:59.640

2020-04-13 17:09:59.796,/yyyy/defoe/v1/aaaaaaaaaal/,2020-04-13 17:09:59.523,2020-04-13 17:09:59.796

2020-04-13 17:09:59.780,/dcd/manual/v2/profile/,2020-04-16 09:59:59.740,2020-04-16 09:59:59.825
```